# Read specific csv files (name should satisfy condition) by python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have million of files in the folder, each named **year-month.csv**

How can I read in one dataframe all the files from the specific year (let's say 2022 or a range *year1 - year2*)?

What is the best data structure to use for such large amount of data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal working example it's hard to be specific but as a starting point you could try something along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df_dict = {}

def load_csv(year, directory):
    
    # create a file list
    file_list = [x for x in os.listdir(path=directory) if x.endswith('.csv')]
    
    # iterate file names
    for i in file_list:
        # split file name
        y, m = i.split('.')[0].split('-')
        
        # if file name meets criterion create a new df add it to dict
        if y == str(year):
            df_dict[i] = pd.read_csv(directory + i)
    
    # concatenate all dfs, set axis to concatenate columns or rows
    df_year = pd.concat([df_dict[i] for i in df_dict], axis=0)
    
    return df_year
```

HDF5 is data format well suited for huge amounts of numerical data. Luckily there is a [package for python](https://www.h5py.org/).

If you are looking for an alternative to pandas which handles large datasets you could try [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) or [Vaex](https://vaex.io/docs/index.html), which have a pandas like API.

Answer (score 0):

Use dask and glob syntax.

Glob syntax will let you filter the filenames and dask will let you parallelize/distribute the read/load.

Comment: How do I filter using glob?

Comment: @Mary check https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html and https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-glob-patterns/